# How can I call `IPython.start_ipython()` with my own banner?

Tags: python, ipython

## What works

When calling `IPython.embed()`, one can pass `banner1`, `banner2` or `header` to customize the message that appears before the interactive session, like this:

```
import IPython
IPython.embed(banner2="*** Welcome! ***")
```

With the result:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 3.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

*** Welcome! ***
In [1]:
```

## What doesn't work

When using `IPython.start_ipython()`, instead of `IPython.embed()` in the invocation above, I couldn't find any parameters that would influence the banner, except `display_banner=False` to omit the it entirely.

The best I could do was to mangle `argv`, to change the configuration, like:

```
import sys, IPython
argv = (
    sys.argv[1:] + 
    ['--TerminalInteractiveShell.banner2=*** Welcome! ***']
)
IPython.start_ipython(argv=argv)
```

This is usable but looks contrived.

I suppose I could also inherit from `IPython.ipapp.TerminalInteractiveShell` in my code and override `.banner1` or `.banner2`, but this feels like overkill.

## The Question

All I want is a way to pass `banner2` into `IPython.start_ipython()`.

Is there a more straightforward way?

## More Technical details

The use case is to create a script that starts an IPython console session with some pre-defined variables for controlling an application with a fairly involved setup. And explain how to use the setup.

Something like:

```
import sys, myapp, IPython

explain_usage_of_session = """
You can use session.blah() to frobnicate the foobaringo
"""

session = myapp.MyComplicatedSessionFactory(including=
    configuration.params(from_file))

sys.exit(
    IPython.start_ipython(user_ns=dict(session=session),
                          banner2=explain_usage_of_session)
)
```

## Constraints

The more specific use-case is that this script is being generated automatically by `buildout`'s `zc.recipe.egg`, which locates `IPython.start_ipython` using `IPython` `[console_scripts]` entry point, so I'm limited in the amount of customization I can actually pass into the script, and I can't use `IPython.embed()` directly.

The super duper plus specific use-case is that I'm actually using `anybox.recipe.odoo`, which wraps `zc.recipe.egg`. The end result is that I'm even more limited in how the script is built.

Basically I can just set the parameters that are passed into `IPython.start_ipython()` call as with the  `arguments` option of `zc.recipe.egg`, and nothing else. In particular, I can't use the `initialization` option of `zc.recipe.egg`.

And I'd rather not have to write my own entry-point.

Comment: You could probably create a Config object, set the necessary parameters and pass it in, but it's probably simpler just to `print()` your own message and then call IPython with `display_banner=False`?

Comment: Have you got a solution? :-)

Comment: @pushpen.paul, other than `display_banner=False` no. And for now I've stopped looking. I suppose a wishlist bug should be opened against IPython.

Answer (score 3):

As [@Thomas K](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613804/how-can-i-call-ipython-start-ipython-with-my-own-banner#comment51183160_31613804) said, you can create an `IPython.Config` instance and set the `banner2`:

```
from IPython import start_ipython
from traitlets.config.loader import Config

c = Config()
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.banner2 = '*** Welcome! ***'

start_ipython(config=c)
```

The result:

```
$ python start_with_banner.py
Python 2.7.11+ (default, Mar 30 2016, 21:00:42) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.4.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

*** Welcome! ***
In [1]:
```

Ftr: the `Config` constructor accepts `kwargs`:

```
c = Config(TerminalInteractiveShell={'banner2': '*** Welcome! ***'})
```

Hth,
dtk

**Update:** For versions before ipython 5.x, you could directly `from IPython import Config`.